# A doubt on the algorithm Cross-Track Distance in Java Code

Tags: java, bearing

I was researching a way to calculate the shortest distance between a coordinated and a straight when I met the Cross-Track Distance. To find the distance, I had to implement the following code:

```
final int EarthRadius = 6371; //in kilometers
double lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2, lon3, lat3;

double brng13 = bearing(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2); // in degrees
double brng12 = bearing(lat1, lon1, lat3, lon3); //  in degrees
double dist13 = harvesine(lat1, lon1, lat3, lon3); // in kilometers

double crosstrack = Math.asin(Math.sin(dist13/EarthRadius)*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(brng13 - brng12))) * EarthRadius;
```

As I'm implementing the code in Java, functions like sine and cosine receive as argument an angle in radians. Therefore, the line of the cross track should be like this:

```
double crosstrack = Math.asin(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(dist13/EarthRadius))*Math.sin(Math.toRadians(brng13 - brng12))) * EarthRadius;
```

The problem is that during my research, I found several codes in Java without converting "***dist13/EarthRadius***" to radians.

What is the correct way? Convert to radians or not?

**Edited** - Added missing java functions:

```
public static double haversine(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
        double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
        lat1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
        lat2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);

        double a = Math.pow(Math.sin(dLat / 2),2) + Math.pow(Math.sin(dLon / 2),2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
        double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
        return EarthRadius  * c;
    }
public static double bearing(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2){
  double longitude1 = lon1;
  double longitude2 = lon2;
  double latitude1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
  double latitude2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);
  double longDiff= Math.toRadians(longitude2-longitude1);
  double y= Math.sin(longDiff)*Math.cos(latitude2);
  double x=Math.cos(latitude1)*Math.sin(latitude2)-Math.sin(latitude1)*Math.cos(latitude2)*Math.cos(longDiff);

  return (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, x))+360)%360;
}
```

Comment: If you think your Haversine is in metres, your radius probably needs to be in metres too. In any case, what do your test cases show?

Comment: In fact, the result of harvesine and the Earth radius value are in Kilometres. I'll fix it.

When I include Math.toRadians (), the algorithm typically runs at a good speed. When the conversion isn't performed, the performance drops significantly.

Comment: For tests, I meant that you should have test cases (like JUnit unit tests) that check for reasonable results. That will tell you if you are doing it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after reading some texts on the formula, I got the answer I needed.

In this article (http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), I found the formula's description:

```
Formula:    dxt = asin( sin(δ13) ⋅ sin(θ13−θ12) ) ⋅ R
where   

δ13 is (angular) distance from start point to third point
θ13 is (initial) bearing from start point to third point
θ12 is (initial) bearing from start point to end point
R is the earth’s radius
```

δ13 is the result of "dist13/Earth_Radius".

But this angle is in radians or degrees? After consulting the book **[Geographical Information Systems and Computer Cartography](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=5Ix9AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA68&lpg=PA68&dq=angular%20distance%20between%20two%20points%20on%20earth&source=bl&ots=EXCQ8zq9D4&sig=xsM8_F2cDnTMmhRcBVokXiDUsNI&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCyaLhq7fPAhVEQ5AKHeRkCvQ4FBDoAQhDMAU#v=onepage&q=angular%20distance%20between%20two%20points%20on%20earth&f=false)**  in 67-66 pages, I saw that the angular distance is given in radians. That is, you do not need conversion.

Incidentally, the formula "δ13 = dist13/Earth_Radius" is a variation of the formula to find the distance between two points on earth, dist13 = δ13*Earth_Radius.